# Background Location not working

Tags: ios

I've added

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
```

to plist file to get background location working and I started location update. but I notice it's not working anymore, although , it was working fine before.

does this has anything to do with upgrade to 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fix it after wasting some time:

I removed

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>location</string>
</array>
```

than I reinstall application, than again, I add it & reinstall app. it worked.

Comment: One of possible reason of this strange behavior is that you (user) press "no" when app asked you about availability to work with location service.